# Render .3ds file on browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, 3d

I need to render a simple .3ds file on the browser. I'm working with vue.js. I've tried the examples on https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master and it works fine.

However, when i try to use a different 3d file and alter the code a bit, only a white screen appears and no errors on the console.

Here's the link of the 3d file I'm trying to render.
https://free3d.com/3d-model/star-wars-victory-93028.html

**VUE**

```
<template>
 <div id="container"></div>
</template>
<script>
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { TDSLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/TDSLoader.js';
import { TrackballControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js';

var container, controls;
var camera, scene, renderer;

export default {
    methods:{
        init() {
            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10 );
            camera.position.z = 2;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color('white')
            scene.add( new THREE.HemisphereLight() );

            var loader = new TDSLoader( );
            loader.load('model/starwars.3ds', function ( object ) {
                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child.isMesh ) {
                        child.material.specular.setScalar( 1 );
                    }
                } );
                scene.add( object );

            } );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            controls = new TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

        },
        animate() {
            controls.update();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            requestAnimationFrame( this.animate );
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.init()
        this.animate()
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Um, it seems the loader is not able to properly load the asset. The colors look definitely wrong. Could be a duplicate of https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/19817

Comment: i think the color is correct. When i change to 'blue' it becomes blue, red becomes red and so on @Mugen87

Comment: plus, i just alter some of the codes in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master @Mugen87